# How to repair obscured blocks in a QR code image

Tags: python, r, imagemagick, barcode, zbar

I have many RGB images that contain a printed sheet of paper with a QR code in an outdoor setting. Because of the bright sun interfering with image capture, about 20% of images are unreadable:

[image]

I'm using `magick` in R to handle the image manipulation, and then the Python package `pyzbar` (which wraps `zbar`) to do the detection.

I can use `image_threshold` to find all the pixels that are within the 95% quantile and force them to pure black, which fixes about half my images:

[image]

But some of them remain unreadable, like this one. I can see with my human eyes that I need to fill in some of the anchor points in the upper left, so I mocked this up in MS Paint:

[image]

With that manual manipulation, this image is now easily read. Is there any way to do this kind of repair automatically? I don't mind translating code from Python or the ImageMagick CLI, so R-only answers aren't necessary.

My general approach:

```
library(magick)
library(reticulate)
pyzbar <- import("pyzbar.pyzbar")

magick_to_numpy <- function(img) {
  round(255 * as.numeric(magick::image_data(img, "rgb")))
}

image_read("testfile.jpg") %>% 
  image_threshold("black", "95%") %>% 
  magick_to_numpy() %>% 
  pyzbar$decode()
```

Usual result:

> ```
> list()
> ```

Desired result:

> ```
> [[1]]
> Decoded(data=b'W TRR C6 T2', type='QRCODE', 
> rect=Rect(left=176, top=221, width=373, height=333), 
> polygon=[Point(x=176, y=226), Point(x=202, y=554), 
> Point(x=549, y=544), Point(x=524, y=221)])
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to improve some of your images, but the one you provided has lost too much black to pure white. So gaps will appear that are too large to close up. The best way I know in Imagemagick command line, would be to process the image converted to grayscale using -lat (local area thresholding) and perhaps some morphology open.

Input:

[image]

```
convert img.jpg -colorspace gray -negate -lat 50x50-1% -negate -morphology open square:7 result.png
```

[image]

Normally one would use the % term as positive. But here you have lost too much data and I want to include as much as possible that is not pure white before it makes too much black. So I push it to -1%. The -negate is needed since -lat works only on white objects on black background. So I have to negate before and after. I then try to fill some the black regions using some morphology open.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out! Works with https://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/ so far, I'll test it on my machine tomorrow.

Comment: You may have to tweak some of the values for each image you have.

Comment: Hmm, this is confusing. I translated the CLI codes into the R package functions, and the output was similar, but not exactly the same (but unreadable). So I then went to making a direct system call to the CLI and got a photo that looked identical to your output, but was unreadable, even though your image is readable! Now I'm fiddling with the parameters, which has recovered about 20% of the previously unrecoverable images.

Comment: What is your version of ImageMagick? If IM 7, then replace convert with magick. What platform/OS?  If your IM is old, then upgrade. You may have a version that was buggy or had undeveloped morphology. I was using IM 6.9.10.56 Q16 Mac OSX.

Comment: I'm using 7.0.6-5, so I'll try it with `magick` instead of `convert`.

Comment: the magic bullet I eventually figured out was resizing! Manipulating the image to death worked occasionally, but I just found that all the barcode reading algorithms fail on high-res photos. I think that's why the versions pasted into here worked, they were resized to be fewer pixels.